# Get human-readable colors from image

Tags: android, colors, bitmap

I want to convert a bitmap with colored squares to an array of Strings being the names of the colors in the squares.
I am facing some issues :

1. Color may vary, as it comes from a phone camera and therefore it may not be the same on all phone and context (light, camera saturation)
2. Squares are not exactly of one color. See example below.

Example :

[image: Original picture]

And I need to return something like this :

```
{"blue", "green", "white", "yellow", "orange", "blue", "green", "orange"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use [Palette](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.html) Helper Class, it helps extract colors from a bitmap, however the number is limited.

Here's a nice article on how to use it.
[Extracting Colors to a Palette with Android Lollipop](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/extracting-colors-to-a-palette-with-android-lollipop/)

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Just a question, can I get the coordinates of the pixels with a specific color, or get the colors in the same order as the picture ?

Comment: I finally used kNN (k nearest neighbour)